# Flask Sqlalchemy Oracle TypeError: id() takes exactly one argument (0 given)

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Flask Sqlalchemy Model

```
class Supplier(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'SUPPLIER'

    supplier_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    supplier_name = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    enable = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=True)
    insert_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
```

When I m trying to add a new supplier, I got the error

```
db.session.add(Supplier(supplier_name="sup"))
db.session.commit()
```

Stack Trace:

```
            db.session.add(supplier_name="sup")
      File "<string>", line 2, in __init__
      File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\instrumentation.py", line 376, in _new_state_if_none
        state = self._state_constructor(instance, self)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 883, in __get__
        obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = result = self.fget(obj)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\instrumentation.py", line 202, in _state_constructor
        self.dispatch.first_init(self, self.class_)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\event\attr.py", line 322, in __call__
        fn(*args, **kw)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\mapper.py", line 3367, in _event_on_first_init
        configure_mappers()
      File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\mapper.py", line 3255, in configure_mappers
        mapper._post_configure_properties()
      File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\mapper.py", line 1950, in _post_configure_properties
        prop.init()
      File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\interfaces.py", line 196, in init
        self.do_init()
      File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\relationships.py", line 1983, in do_init
        self._process_dependent_arguments()
      File "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\python37_64\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\relationships.py", line 2012, in _process_dependent_arguments
        setattr(self, attr, attr_value())
    TypeError: id() takes exactly one argument (0 given)
```

I already tried the below methods, but still not working.

1. add Sequence

   ```
   id_seq = db.Sequence('id_seq')
   supplier_id = db.Column(db.Integer, id_seq, server_default=id_seq.next_value(), primary_key=True)
   ```
2. add constructor

   ```
    def __init__(self, supplier_name):
        self.supplier_name = supplier_name
   ```

I already make sure the table exists, and all columns been generated successfully.
Seems not only this table has this issue, but any table I insert will also raise this error.
Previously I use PostgresDB no issue, now I switch to oracle have this error.
Please help!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out myself.

[image: Pic]

Last 3 lines, remote_side should be "node_id" not "id"

Comment: See, those lines where not even mentioned in the question ;)

Comment: Yes, I didn't know it's model issue, because create_all_table and drop_all_table both no error.